# Ansible Fetching first few characters of a variable

Tags: ansible

```
EC2_INSTANCE_ID=i-01a0eb178c5e9fe94
export EC2_INSTANCE_ID
```

ansible variable file:

```
ec2_inst_id: "{{ lookup('env','EC2_INSTANCE_ID') }}"
```

How do I select only this part of the `EC2_INSTANCE_ID`
"i-01a0eb" only the first few characters

Please help. The variable is on a `ansible` `playbook`

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just python code being evaluated inside the brackets `{{ ... }}`?

Could you try the following:

```
ec2_inst_id: "{{ lookup('env','EC2_INSTANCE_ID')[:8] }}"
```

Comment: This will do. But to be precise, `{{ ... }}` is a Jinja2 expression, and only a subset of Python can be used inside it.